# javascript indentation in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

hallo all 
i was wondering how i can change the indentation settings of vs2010
so instead of it doing this:

```
function test () {
}
```

it will do this:

```
function test ()
{

}
```

its bugging me out!

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010, go:

1. Tools > Options.
2. Expand the Text Editor node and select **JScript**. (a.k.a JavaScript).
3. Under Formatting, tick the "Place open brace on new line for functions" checkbox.

[Screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cd7619316f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cd7619316f.png)

Answer (score 2):

You might not want to actually do that.

It is set by default to be on the same line because in JavaScript brace placement matters. Although not always, not having the brace there can lead to bad interpretation of your code.

A good blog article on this is: http://encosia.com/2011/03/21/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/

Although a developer can code for this, good habits breed good code, and this is a habit you might want to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options

Check "Show all settings"

Text editor > JScript > Formatting

Uncheck "Place open brace on new line for functions"